# Navigation won't stay in place like I want

Tags: css, html, navigation, navbar

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXB4G.png
  [2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub3PN.png

The first image [1] is how I **want** the nav to stay all the time (on the left of the middle div which is centered), but as seen in the second image [2] it overlaps or doesn't really LOCK on the the left side of the main div where my info will be going... help please, my first time building a website from scratch!

HTML:

```
<div id="header" class="wrapper,class">
        <img src="images/header.png">
    </div>

    <div id="nav" class="containerleft">
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Home</a></li><br/>
        <li><a href="#2">News</a></li><br/>
        <li><a href="#3">Music</a></li><br/>
        <li><a href="#4">Videos</a></li><br/>
        <li><a href="#5">Photos</a></li><br/>
        <li><a href="#6">Store</a></li><br/>
        <li><a href="#7">Contact</a></li><br/>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="main" class="center">
    testing text here in my main div!



    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header
{
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#nav
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: auto;
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
        text-align: right;
}

#main
{
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
        background-image:url(images/main_box.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        width: 668px;
        height: 578px;
}
```

Comment: You should put your #nav inside the #main div, and use a negative `left` value to push #nav to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to do anything without the images or sizes.  I think if you give you #nav a width such as `width: 300px;`  and make sure they are in separate div's or containers you should get the effect you're looking for.

If you could come up with an example on jsFiddle i'd be glad to toy around with it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do this by floating the div tags and then positioning them using their widths as demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QgcL9/

Giving a class these allows you to float them.

```
float:left;
width: 500px;
```

If you make sure to clear the floats you can then position elemnts anywhere on the page as normal around this.

There is also some usefull examples on this sort of positioning here:
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/